# Post Request to Auth0 Users Endpoint working with postman, but not with my .netCore web Api

Tags: post, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, restsharp

I'm stuck for several hours with my POST method. It works fine when I use postman to reach the users endpoint from Auth0 to create a new user, but when I call it from my API, I got a 400 NOT FOUND... And it seems that the body is empty.

Here is the code request and the body sended by postman.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> PostUser([FromBody]Object content)
    {
        string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(content);
        var client = new RestClient($"https://{configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/api/v2/users/");

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("authorization", $"Bearer eyJhbG....");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        return Ok(response.Content);
    }
```

this is the postman body, in raw json format and the url for the API post endpoint
url : http://localhost:18033/api/users/
body:

```
{
"email": "user10@gmail.com",
"given_name": "Henri",
"family_name": "Doe",
"picture": "https://i.pravatar.cc/300",
"connection": "Username-Password-Authentication",
"password": "123Soleil!"
}
```

any idea ? Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you use tools like fiddler to catch both your request and compare their difference? What I can see from your above post is that the url in your code is `api/v2/users` but in postman is `api/users`